# best ffmpeg settings for iSpy server

Tags: camera, ffmpeg

At the moment I have setup streaming via nginx rtmp-module wrapped in FLV h264. This works really great for integrating into a website. But now I want to actually record and do motion analysis and some registration number recognition.

I am using iSpy 64bit on a dedicated machine and it seems to crash allot when I use the RTMP stream in the ffmpeg tab.

Does any body know what the best setting for ffmpeg I can use so that iSpy can connect to without any hassle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most stable settings for me are is to use a script file, fifo and the [psips](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=364825#p364825) script to dump mpegts video over udp

```
rm -f "$fifo"
mkfifo "$fifo"

raspivid -ex auto -mm matrix -w 720-h 576 -fps 10 -t 0 -b 1000000 -o - | psips > "$fifo" &


ffmpeg -y \
  -f h264 \
  -i "$fifo" \
  -c:v copy \
  -map 0:0 \
  -f mpegts udp:192.168.1.88:1234
```

Then I used iSpy vlc plugin 
[image]

When I try to use rtmp with nginx then iSpy crashes allot and it totally floods my WiFi.

Using udp means the Pi will dump the frames to the target machine and neither the source or destination is going to cry about lost frames saving allot of processing power. Using 576p the pi hardly uses 1% cpu and the cpu usage on iSpy is halved for processiing motion.